# Sharepoint 2010 foundation and WAMP server on same machine (Win 7)

Tags: sharepoint, wamp

I've earlier installed sharepoint 2010 foundation on my win 7 notebook. recently installed wamp serever. Now when i try to access localhost though wamp i'm getting 404 error.  Is there a chance both SP foundation 2010 and wamp can co-exist on the same machine.

Need help badly

Answer (score 0):

Port conflict I should think, need to set apache up to use something other than port 80